# What's the accurate definition of a compiler?

Tags: compilers

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler):

> In computing, a compiler is a computer program that translates computer code written in one programming language (the source language) into another language (the target language).

This implies that the compiler can also convert from a low-level language to a high-level language. But this has also got a specific name [decompiler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler).

So what should be the definition for a compiler? 1) or 2)?

1. In computing, a compiler is a computer program that translates computer code written in one programming language (the source language) into another language (the target language).
2. A compiler is a computer program that translates computer code written in a high-level programming language into a low-level language.

Comment: *Compiler* is an informal term. It doesn't have a formal definition.

Comment: The *very next sentence* after the excerpt you quote addresses your concern, and basically implicitly answers the question you are asking.  I think it would have been helpful to mention that and use that to improve your question.

Comment: @Yuval Filmus So if software converts a low-level language to a high-level language, is it a compiler or a decompiler? I am confused by the definitions.

Comment: @D.W.♦ So if software converts a low-level language to a high-level language, is it a compiler or a decompiler? I am confused by the definitions.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment points out, there's not a formal definition for "compiler", instead it's understood to be that program which translates source code into the target language. Both definitions given are adequate. The definition in Wikipedia is a good one:

> In computing, a compiler is a computer program that translates
> computer code written in one programming language (the source
> language) into another language (the target language). The name
> "compiler" is primarily used for programs that translate source code
> from a high-level programming language to a lower level language
> (e.g., assembly language, object code, or machine code) to create an
> executable program.

Comment: So if it converts a low-level language to a high-level language, is it a compiler or a decompiler? I am confused by the definitions.

Comment: Isn't the second definition missing something that the Wikipedia definition has? How are they both adequate?

Comment: Are "decompilers" and "transpilers" types of compilers?

Comment: Decompilers come up less frequently than compilers; a decompiler is understood to be a program which takes the executable (or object code or other lower-level code) and outputs a higher level source code which would if compiled compile into that given input. In other words, it's the reverse of a compiler. Note though that the source code that comes out of decompilers is typically not very "well-written" and is unlikely to match the actual source code used.

Answer (score 0):

Mr Raut. I did some research on your question and here is what I found:

“[A compiler  is ] Computer software that translates (compiles) source code written in a high-level language (e.g., C++) into a set of machine-language instructions that can be understood by a digital computer’s CPU. [...]
Some compilers translate high-level language into an intermediate assembly language, which is then translated (assembled) into machine code by an assembly program or assembler. Other compilers generate machine language directly. ”

I found this on Encyclopaedia Britannica (https://www.britannica.com/technology/compiler). This implies that #2 is the preferred answer.